# ViewStateMode ="disabled" do not disable viewstae for all elements

Tags: asp.net-4.0, viewstate

I have one Page in my Web Application , To reduce the ViewState Size , I have made `ViewStateMode = "false"` in `@Page Directive`

I have Repeater control and I bind input check-box in it , as below

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptChkList" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="clear">
                <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("Value")' />
                 <%# Eval("Name")%>
            </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Although I have set `ViewStateMode ="false"` , I m getting `DataBoundLiteralControl`, `HtmlInputCheckBox` in ViewState

Can any body have idea How to make its `ViewState` false??

Answer (score 0):

You can set ViewState property of repeater control itself.

Answer (score 0):

For disabling ViewState at the page level set:

```
EnableViewState="false"
```

**Note:** The ViewStateMode property of a page or a control has an effect only if the EnableViewState property is set to true. If the EnableViewState property is set to false, view state will be turned off even if the ViewStateMode property is set to Enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In the page directive you need to have the following:

```
ViewStateMode="Disabled"
```

To enable for a specific control, you need to have it in the control, like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStateList" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
```